# Climbing without moving, how do you say that?

Tags: idioms

Climbing without moving, how do you say that? Running without moving on a treadmil would be running in place, but climbing on a sort of treadmill would be climbing in place? Is that an idiom, or there's no set idiom for this?

Answer (score 7):

"Running in place" means making running motions without moving forward, rather than on a treadmill.  In British English the expression is "running on the spot".  When you are on a treadmill you "run", you don't "run in place".

That's a fairly normal thing to do. I can't imagine how one would make climbing motions up a wall without climbing. I've found a few "climbing treadmills", but just as with regular treadmills, you don't "climb in place" on them, you just "climb".

So there is no idiom for this as a literal activity.  Perhaps you want to use this as a metaphor "climbing the business ladder without getting any higher".  I think you just need to say "climbing without moving".  Perhaps "climbing in place" would be understood as an analogy.

> I feel like I'm "climbing in place" at XYZ corp. My job title changes, but I don't get any more responsibility or better pay.

But as a metaphor, "running in place" or "running on the spot" is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually go up, which I believe is what you mean, then you could say 'ascending' (like in a lift/elevator for instance).
This can also be applied for non-physical 'going up', e.g. 'ascending to a higher spiritual state'.

Comment: It appears the OP does not mean ascending, but rather being on a [climbing wall that shifts as you climb it](https://youtu.be/jVyhr7bEJ9E?t=15), thus keeping you in place.

Comment: What do you mean 'appears'? OP does mention a treadmill but to me that looks like it's for comparision with a running treadmill. @Sayaman perhaps you could clear this up :)

Comment: If you're that aware of what the OP has asked, then I don't see how you expected the given answer to actually be applicable to the question.